# How to get touch coordinates REGARDLESS of what "view" I may have touched?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview, uiwindow

In my ViewController, I have a UITableView with some custom cells in it. When I touch a cell I want to get the touch coordinates right there into my UIViewController. The problem is, I can only get coordinates from parts of the screen not occupied by the UITableView..., Whenever my touch falls in the parts of the screen with the UITableView, my coords are NSLogged back as (0.000, 0.000). How can I get coordinates of the screen REGARDLESS of whichever view happened to get the touch? Do I start from UIScreen? UIWindow?...

Question: How to get touch coordinates REGARDLESS of what "view" I may have touched?

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to achieve - there might be a better way of doing it.

Comment: I was trying to know the coordinates I touched in my UITableViewCell (custom) so I could calculate, by the x-coordinate of the touch, which of the four UIImageViews (not accessory views) contained in the cell were touched. Trying to get touch points from the calling ViewController didn't (Got cell row but not touch point in cell) work, and trying to implement touch handling from the custom cell seemed to disable certain delegate methods of the view controller (Got cell touch coords but no cell row)...Finally I ended up subclassing UITableView and used HitTest which worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have UITableView pick touches up and report them to its viewcontroller which can in turn report it to the other view controler, or something of that matter. Im not sure if setting the tableView opaquew will allow touches to go to the underneath touch, but you can try that if you havent.